# Processing RGB Wheel to control Arduino RGB LED

Tags: arduino, processing, rgb

I would like to make a RGB wheel in processing as a GUI to control the LED color of a RGB Led connected to an Arduino Board.

I have done this code in Processing so far.

```
float startFill;
float startAngle;
int step;
float stepLength;

float centerX;
float centerY;

float pSize;
float bValue;

void setup()
{
  size(512, 512);
  colorMode(HSB, 2*PI, 100, 100);
  smooth();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0,0,25);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();

  step = 120;
  centerX = width/2;
  centerY = height/2;
  startFill = 0;
  startAngle = 0;
  stepLength = PI/step;

  pSize = 400;
  bValue = 200;

  // draw arcs
  for(int i=0; i< 2*step; i++)
  {
     for(int j=0; j< step; j++)
     {
         fill(startFill, bValue, 100,80);
         stroke(0,0,95,20);
         arc(centerX, centerY, pSize, pSize, startAngle, startAngle+stepLength);

         bValue = bValue - 50/step;
         pSize = pSize - 50/step;
      }   
      startFill =  startFill + stepLength;
      startAngle = startAngle + stepLength;
  }  
}
```

I would like to map the values of Red, Green and Blue using the mouse position on the screen over the previous wheel.

I found a picture that would help me as guide  to write the RGB values over the mouse position on the wheel but I'm not very sure how to make that.

[RGB WHEEL PROCESSING](http://bluelobsterart.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/rgb-color-wheel-lg.jpg)

I would really appreciate any help or advice.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that that color wheel is not actuall a color wheel. It's just "the same color, going in". The outer circle is your standard color mix, pure R at angle ..., pure G at angle ...+2/4*pi, and pure B at angle ...+4/3*pi. For activation purposes, construct a color wedge object and use that:

```java
class ColorWedge {
  color c;
  float[] coords;
  ColorWedge(color _c, float[] _coords) {
    c = _c;
    coords = _coords;
  }
  void draw() {
    fill(c);
    noStroke();
    triangle(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3],coords[4],coords[5]);
    stroke(0);
    line(coords[2],coords[3],coords[4],coords[5]);
  }
}
```

And then construct wedges for "all" the colors by creating wedges over an angle:

```java
final float PI2 = 2*PI;
ArrayList<ColorWedge> wedges; 

void setup() {
  size(200,200);
  colorMode(HSB,PI2);
  wedges = new ArrayList<ColorWedge>();
  float radius = 90,
        ox = width/2,
        oy = height/2,
        px, py, nx, ny,
        step = 0.01,
        overlap = step*0.6;
  for(float a=0; a<PI2; a+=step) {
    px = ox + radius * cos(a-overlap);
    py = oy + radius * sin(a-overlap);
    nx = ox + radius * cos(a+overlap);
    ny = oy + radius * sin(a+overlap);
    wedges.add(new ColorWedge(color(a,PI2,PI2), new float[]{ox,oy,px,py,nx,ny}));
  }
}
```

Controlling the color is then simply a matter of figuring out where the mouse is, and that its angle to the center of the sketch is:

```java
color wcolor = 0;

void draw() {
  background(PI2,0,PI2);
  pushStyle();
  for(ColorWedge w: wedges) { w.draw(); }

  strokeWeight(10);
  stroke(wcolor);
  line(0,0,width,0);
  line(width,0,width,height);
  line(width,height,0,height);
  line(0,height,0,0);
  popStyle();
}

void mouseMoved() {
  float angle = atan2(mouseY-height/2,mouseX-width/2);
  if(angle<0) angle+=PI2;
  ColorWedge wedge = wedges.get((int)map(angle,0,PI2,0,wedges.size()));
  wcolor = wedge.c;
}
```

That should get you well on your way, if not 100% of the way there.

Comment: The code is working really nice!! Thank you very much! I would like to mention you on Youtube's comments once I finish the full code and upload the video if I have your permission :).

Comment: Go for it. I'm Pomax, one of the Processing.js developers =)

Comment: Video done :D Here it is: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgAxA4rl8y4&feature=youtu.be
Thank you very much Pomax! I will upload to my web page www.andruinnova.es as soon as I finish creating the content.